# do you trick? (what does that mean?)

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

From the movie [Nightcrawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcrawler_%28film%29) (2014)

Example:

> — So... What's your address, Richard?
>   — I don't have one. Not a permanent one right now.
>   — You're homeless.
>   — I was for a while.
>   — You **trick**.
>   — Work the street? No.
>   — Wasn't a question.
>   — I'm straight.
>   — Plenty of straight guys **trick**. Do you have a driver's license?
>   — Yeah.
>   — Do you know Los Angeles?
>   — Yeah. I grew up all around here.

What does he mean by *trick*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Trick" here means the act of prostitution.

A common phrase used for when a prostitute performs a service for a customer is "turn a trick" or "turning tricks."

This example shortens the phrase, and then sort of turns it into a verb. "Verbing nouns and Nouning verbs" is common in english.

Comment: "work the street" can also be a term for selling sexual services.

Answer (score 2):

"Trick" or "turn tricks" is a euphemism for prostitution.